# Jacobbian Transformation Multiple Integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The question says :

Sketch the region under the transformation of u=x+y and v=y for

$$R=\{(x,y): 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1 , 0\leqslant y \leqslant1\}$$

Find the Area of the region.

Given answer is $1$

I just need help on the calculation of the area. No need to draw the graph. Could someone guide me to start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the set $R(x,y)$ is the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$. You are looking for the transformation of variables

$$(x,y)\mapsto (u-v,v).$$

To deduce it I used the definitions of $u$, and $v$. In fact:  $u=x+y$ implies $x=u-y$; as $v=y$, we arrive at  $x=u-v$. Now you need to find the image of the square $R(x,y)$ under the above coordinate transformation. In other words, you need to solve the inequalities

$$0\leq u-v\leq 1$$

and

$$0\leq v\leq 1$$

(in this second case there is nothing to do!). Can you draw the set  $\tilde{R}(u,v)=\{(u,v):  0\leq u-v\leq 1, 0\leq v\leq 1\}$ in the $u$-$v$-plane?

Once the geometry is clear, in order to find the surface of $\tilde{R}(u,v)$ you need to compute the integral

$\Sigma_{\tilde{R}(u,v)}=\int_{\tilde{R}(u,v)}dudv=...$

and the exercise is done.

Comment: Thanks avitus. I got it and manage to solve it. =)